# Application.Match formula Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed the code below using the `Application.Match` function.

The statement that I wish to execute when I get an error in my first `Application.Match` (tested for by using `IsError(x)`) does not appear to be executed.

My intention is that, if the first `Application.Match` returns an error, I would like my code to perform the same match but with the search item being a date which is one day earlier than the original match.

My code:

```
Sub macro1()

    i = 8
    Dim xx As Date

    For a = 1 To 3
        x = Application.Match(Sheets("Dump"). _
                Cells(1, i), Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C1"), 0)

        Set aa = Sheets("Dump").Cells(1, i)
        xx = aa - 1
        If IsError(x) Then x = Application.Match(xx, Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C1"), 0)    
        Sheets("Dump").Cells(2, i) = x

        i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Sheet "Dump":

[image]

Sheet "Sheet2":

[image]

Comment: I can find only `WorksheetFunction.Match` method, not `Application.Match`.

Comment: @EganWolf read at MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx (see example in the middle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IsError` is working, and your second `Application.Match` is being executed.  The problem is that it too is returning an error and so you just think that it hasn't been executed.

You need to cast the `Date` to a `Double` in order for the `Match` to work using a variable:

```
If IsError(x) Then x = Application.Match(CDbl(xx), Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C1"), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I have made the changes and its work absolutely correct now just requesting you Kindly explain why we change variable from date to Double and what is "CDbl".

Comment: `CDbl` casts (i.e. "converts") a variable to be a double precision number.  `Match` doesn't work well with `Dates` because Excel treats dates as a double precision number - using the "Cast to Double" function just allows a like-with-like comparison to be made.  I didn't test it, but you could probably have also got around the problem by just declaring `xx` with a `Dim xx As Double` statement.

Comment: The code is running with both the variables **Date** & **Double** the important aspect is using **CDbl** which convert value xx into Double as I check.

Comment: @sagar - The alternative of declaring `xx` to be a `Double` would mean that the `CDbl` would no longer be needed - the value would already **be** a `Double` and therefore no further type conversion would be required when you go to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To trap the error on `x` if `Application.Match` returned an error use the code below.

Instead of your line:

```
x = Application.Match(Sheets("Dump"). _
    Cells(1, i), Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C1"), 0)
```

use the If `IsError` below :

```
If IsError(Application.Match(Sheets("Dump").Cells(1, i), Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C1"), 0)) Then
    ' do something if error (maybe MsgBox, maybe use Exit Sub)

Else '<-- Match was successful
    x = Application.Match(Sheets("Dump").Cells(1, i), Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:C1"), 0)
End If
```

Comment: The OP's second `Match` needs to be in the `True` leg of your `If` statement, after correcting for the error.

Comment: How is a better way of writing code, a solution to the question. @YowE3K provides a solution.

Comment: sorry, but you are both a little wrong, what will you do if there is no successful match in the first `x`?  how will you handle it?

Comment: May the "brave" downvoter explain why ?

Comment: The OP's code does an `If IsError(x)` - in their example the second date does not match, so `x` contains an error code, and the second `Match` is attempted.  For their first and third date, no error is generated from the first `Match`, so `x` is left unchanged.

Comment: Dear Sir,Basically I have each date wise data in every column in whole spreadsheet and I would like to check the column No. of every 20th day of the every month.thus I am using match function.if 20th day of particular month is not available then match formula will have to consider previous date like 19th.thus please guide how should i code. please refer my shared sheet pictures which make more clarity about my concern.thanks in advance.

Comment: if everyone is happy, then all is good :)

Comment: Further to my previous comment - if you step through the OP's code you will see that (on the second date) the first `Match` sets `x` to be `Variant/Error` - this is what allows the later `IsError` to correctly see that an error was returned.